Create a rotating globe project from codepen
I am using the code project in codepen under the title Create a rotating globe, in its js they noted that for the map to appear I should use my own Mapbox access token.  text
I created a Mapbox account and created a token to use it and still, the map is not showing.
so how could I catch the problem to solve it?
<body>
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.14.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

    <script>
        // TO MAKE THE MAP APPEAR YOU MUST
// ADD YOUR ACCESS TOKEN FROM
// https://account.mapbox.com
mapboxgl.accessToken =
  "pk.eyJ1IjoiZGFuYTQ4MiIsImEiOiJjbHV2Zmg1eWcwMzBtMmltZzhrbjQwNHlsIn0.uwVIhtVR-3ewi7ybQcTeqQ";
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: "map",
  style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
  projection: "globe", // Display the map as a globe, since satellite-v9 defaults to Mercator
  zoom: 1.5,
  center: [-90, 40]
});

map.on("style.load", () => {
  map.setFog({
    range: [0.8, 8],
    color: "#dc9f9f",
    "horizon-blend": 0.5,
    "high-color": "#245bde",
    "space-color": "#000000",
    "star-intensity": 0.15
  }); // Set the default atmosphere style
});

// The following values can be changed to control rotation speed:

// At low zooms, complete a revolution every two minutes.
const secondsPerRevolution = 120;
// Above zoom level 5, do not rotate.
const maxSpinZoom = 5;
// Rotate at intermediate speeds between zoom levels 3 and 5.
const slowSpinZoom = 3;

let userInteracting = false;
let spinEnabled = true;

function spinGlobe() {
  const zoom = map.getZoom();
  if (spinEnabled && !userInteracting && zoom < maxSpinZoom) {
    let distancePerSecond = 360 / secondsPerRevolution;
    if (zoom > slowSpinZoom) {
      // Slow spinning at higher zooms
      const zoomDif = (maxSpinZoom - zoom) / (maxSpinZoom - slowSpinZoom);
      distancePerSecond *= zoomDif;
    }
    const center = map.getCenter();
    center.lng -= distancePerSecond;
    // Smoothly animate the map over one second.
    // When this animation is complete, it calls a 'moveend' event.
    map.easeTo({ center, duration: 1000, easing: (n) => n });
  }
}

// Pause spinning on interaction
map.on("mousedown", () => {
  userInteracting = true;
});

// Restart spinning the globe when interaction is complete
map.on("mouseup", () => {
  userInteracting = false;
  spinGlobe();
});

// These events account for cases where the mouse has moved
// off the map, so 'mouseup' will not be fired.
map.on("dragend", () => {
  userInteracting = false;
  spinGlobe();
});
map.on("pitchend", () => {
  userInteracting = false;
  spinGlobe();
});
map.on("rotateend", () => {
  userInteracting = false;
  spinGlobe();
});

// When animation is complete, start spinning if there is no ongoing interaction
map.on("moveend", () => {
  spinGlobe();
});

document.getElementById("btn-spin").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  spinEnabled = !spinEnabled;
  if (spinEnabled) {
    spinGlobe();
    e.target.innerHTML = "Pause rotation";
  } else {
    map.stop(); // Immediately end ongoing animation
    e.target.innerHTML = "Start rotation";
  }
});

spinGlobe();

    </script>
</body>
</html>

